# Elbow pain due to tricep exercise

Tags: workout, pain, triceps

After doing 'kickbacks', I have started to experience extreme pain in my elbow.

I want to know, what possibly I might have done to cause this pain. Also, I want to know how do I cure the pain? I have taken break from the gym since few days of this pain. It has reduced but it still remains

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have developed [tendonitis](http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/arthritis-tendinitis). Several causes for this problem:

1. **Bad form**. You should either ask someone experienced to take a look at your form or record yourself so that you can watch for any mistakes.
2. **Too heavy too often**. You're using too heavy weight and too often (85%+ 1RM sets 2+ days a week). While your muscles may be ready to take on the weight, your joints and CNS may not.

Follow the [RICE principal](http://www.dukehealth.org/orthopaedics/services/sports-medicine/care-guides/injury-recovery-the-rice-principles) for the most optimal way to recovery. You can also try to go get acupuncture done as well for speedy recovery. You can continue to lift, just not any exercises that induce pain.

Comment: yeah, I think, your 2nd point applies to me. Will follow the RICE principal. Thnx a lot!

Comment: Just adding on, isolation exercises are a great way to get tondonitis. Use a barbell for OHP and do dips.

Answer (score 2):

These two points might seem pretty simple however extremely important and good to know.

1. First rule, **STOP** your workout exactly when injury happened and DO NOT continue the session.
2. In the coming weeks, don't leave the injured muscle/joint isolated due to the injury. The trick is **not** to directly work it directly, but to work **around** it.

In more details:

As soon as you feel something out of the ordinary happened and your instincts are telling you that this is not a normal pain which happens during lifting, stop what ever you you are in your plan are and go home to give the injury the attention it needs. No more reps no more sets.

Some people say, *I just started the workout and I don't want to leave it halfways* and this costs them at best some injury which drags for a long time and at worst a permanent one.

So indirect and controlled (lower than normal weights and intesity), multi-joint moves will be good for the injured part to bring him back to the normal state.

I have dealt with couple of fairly serious injuries including **knee and wrists** and these techniques ,advised by the specialist I consulted with, worked the best.

Good luck

Comment: yeah, I will keep that in mind the next time around. Thnx..:)

Answer (score 0):

If it hurts when you do that, don’t do that.  This answer is pragmatic.

There are certain triceps isolation exercises that I just cannot do in particular triceps kick back and skull crushers.  If I do these exercises over any period of time I will develop painful tendonitis.  If this is tendonitis the only way to help the pain is give it some time.    If you want to work your triceps try a bench variation.

Answer (score 0):

What 'pufferfish' said.
Only do the exercises your body/joints don't react negatively to.
I don't do skullcrushers anymore.
Done them for decades, but nowadays my left elbow and right also if going on, start clicking in an uncomfortable way when doing them. Something going on with the cartilage.
Triceps kickback seems for me more of a rear deltoid exercise than that it works the triceps , to keep the upper arm in that position is unnatural in my experience.
And no, my rear delt is not weak. It's just the exercise, my triceps are strong, and triceps kickback is not effictive enough to load them. Tried is many times, it's not working for me. pushups with hands shoulder width are way more effective in that regard to name one, I do those now without problems (knock on wood). Close grip bench grip is another one could do.
Late response.
But it might help others who have this issue as well. As I learned a lot from others also..